# Как использовать i18n в Pyramid вне темплейтов и вьюх (в формах и моделях например)?

Tags: python

Как можно использовать интернационализацию в фреймворке Pyramid вне темплейтов и вьюх. Встроенных механизмов нет - это я уже проверил...

Для встроенных механизмов интернационализации необходимо передавать параметр `request`, а он то и не боступен вне `view` и `templates`...

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Я не знаком с Pyramid, но если там это сделано по принципу Django - через `gettext/ugettext`, то должно быть можно. Поищите по ключевым словам

Comment: В том-то и дело, что там это делается не так как в Django...

Answer (score 1):

с языком python и уж тем более с фреймворком Pyramid  не знаком. НО суть вопроса вроде как уловил. Так вот вполне логично что интернализацю делают в представлении, а не в моделях или в контроллерах, ведь именно представление и отвечает за то что отобразить юзеру.

Answer (score 0):

Так вне доступа к request Вы и информацию о пользователе (его IP или сессии) не получите. Так о какой интернационализации может идти тогда речь? А если так шибко надо, то в конечном итого все сводится к view и из view Вы можете обращаться к своей модели с указанием request